# How to change radio button's toggle button to an image in wpf (for grouped radio buttons)?

Tags: wpf, xaml, radio-button

I change my radio button's image (when clicked or not) in a `ResourceDictionary` like this:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"
        x:Key="MenuButtonTheme">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image x:Name="SidebarRadioButtonMenuIcon"
                                Source="/UiDesign/Images/SidebarIcons/logout.png"
                                Width="18.57"
                                Height="18.57"
                                Grid.Column="0" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="SidebarRadioButtonMenuText"
                                    Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"
                                    VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                    Foreground="#7D8083"
                                    FontSize="14.59"
                                    FontWeight="Bold"
                                    FontFamily="/UiDesign/Fonts/#Nunito"
                                    Margin="12,0,0,0"
                                    Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                    Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="SidebarRadioButtonMenuText"
                                    Property="Foreground"
                                    Value="#F54342" />
                            <Setter TargetName="SidebarRadioButtonMenuIcon"
                                    Property="Source"
                                    Value="/UiDesign/Images/SidebarIcons/Selected/logout.png" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="Transparent" />
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

The code above is working just fine. But my menu consists of more than 1 radio buttons.

This is how I apply my style:

```xml
<RadioButton Content="Dashboard"
             Grid.Column="1"
             Grid.Row="0"
             Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}" />
```

This is how my buttons look like:

[image]

When I select a menu item, it will look like this:

[image]

[image]

(the images for `IsChecked` true and false are all the same for all my menu items (which are `RadioButton`s))

The question is, do I have to create a `ResourceDictionary` for each button so that their image will change when I select on them (and of course, change their default image)?

This is want I want to achieve:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a group of radio buttons. I already registered the resource dictionary in my app.xaml. Let me update the question for more clarity.

Comment: If the answer below does not answer the problem, I will update it.

Comment: The reason the images are the same is because you gave the same image path for both. Could it be because of this?

The RadioButton painting works when I do it and give different pictures.

Comment: Yes, its just the same for testing purposes. But if I change the default and "selected" images for each item, do I need to create another resource dictionary for each button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a variety of ways to accomplish this but I think the straightforward way is to define a custom RadioButton which has dependency properties for URI strings to images for different states and bind them from XAML.

Let's say, we create **SampleRadioButton** which has `NormalImageUriString` and `CheckedImageUriString` dependency properties and a converter for converting URI string to BitmapImage.

```cs
public class SampleRadioButton : RadioButton
{
    public string NormalImageUriString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NormalImageUriStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NormalImageUriStringProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty NormalImageUriStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NormalImageUriString", typeof(string), typeof(SampleRadioButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public string CheckedImageUriString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(CheckedImageUriStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CheckedImageUriStringProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CheckedImageUriStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("CheckedImageUriString", typeof(string), typeof(SampleRadioButton), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}

public class ImageUriStringConverver : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is not string source)
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        return new BitmapImage(new Uri(source, UriKind.Relative));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And edit XAML to bind these dependency properties using the converter.

```
<local:ImageUriStringConverver x:Key="ImageUriStringConverterKey"/>

<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:SampleRadioButton}">
    <Setter Property="NormalImageUriString" Value="[URI string to default image for normal state]"/>
    <Setter Property="CheckedImageUriString" Value="[URI string to default image for checked state]"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:SampleRadioButton}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    ...
                    <Image x:Name="SidebarRadioButtonMenuIcon"
                           Source="{TemplateBinding NormalImageUriString, Converter={StaticResource ImageUriStringConverterKey}}"
                           ...
                           />
                    <TextBlock x:Name="SidebarRadioButtonMenuText"
                               ...
                               />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="SidebarRadioButtonMenuText" Property="Foreground" Value="#F54342" />
                        <Setter TargetName="SidebarRadioButtonMenuIcon" Property="Source" Value="{Binding CheckedImageUriString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:SampleRadioButton}}}"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then we can set specific images by setting these dependency properties in each **SampleRadioButton**.

```
<local:SampleRadioButton Content="Sample"
                         NormalImageUriString="[URI string to specific image for normal state]"
                         CheckedImageUriString="[URI string to specific image for checked state]"/>
```

Comment: @Hacki, I think this seems to be the ideal solution. When you want to add new features to RadioButton, you can make the necessary arrangements in a single structure.

Comment: Do we really need these in our xaml?  <Setter Property="NormalImageUriString" Value="[URI string to default image for normal state]"/>
    <Setter Property="CheckedImageUriString" Value="[URI string to default image for checked state]"/>

Comment: I tried this, but, my normal/default image is not displayed. However, when I select an image, it now changes its image depending on the menu item I select.

Comment: I can't seem to get the normal/default image to display, so I mixed your answer with @saklanmaz's answer, and now it works! (to my expected behavior)

This answer: changed the RadioButton's image when I select it
saklanmaz's answer: displays the RadioButton's default image (when not selected)

now I don't know who to accept now ;(

Comment: If you choose to set specific images in every SampleRadioButtons, you don't need to set default images. And the correct format of  URI strings to images depend on how you include those images in your application. This is just a sample of what I think the straightforward way.

Comment: I now figured it out! I removed: Setter Property="NormalImageUriString" Value="[URI string to default image for normal state]"/> <Setter Property="CheckedImageUriString" Value="[URI string to default image for checked state]"/> (in resource dictionary answer above), and changed the image source to: {Binding NormalImageUriString, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}} instead of {TemplateBinding NormalImageUriString, Converter={StaticResource ImageUriStringConverterKey}} (your answer)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I think there is no need to change the image in the case of IsChecked. I linked the picture above to the RadioButton Tag (I did it quickly, you can link it to something more convenient.)

You can now use Tag as image address path in your own xaml code.

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<Style TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}"
    x:Key="MenuButtonTheme">
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="RadioButton">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Image x:Name="SidebarRadioButtonMenuIcon"
                            Source="{Binding Path=Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                            Width="18.57"
                            Height="18.57"
                            Grid.Column="0" />
                        <TextBlock x:Name="SidebarRadioButtonMenuText"
                                Text="{TemplateBinding Property=Content}"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                Foreground="#7D8083"
                                FontSize="14.59"
                                FontWeight="Bold"
                                FontFamily="/UiDesign/Fonts/#Nunito"
                                Margin="12,0,0,0"
                                Grid.Column="1" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="SidebarRadioButtonMenuText"
                                Property="Foreground"
                                Value="#F54342" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

***MainWindow.xaml***

```
            <RadioButton Content="Dashboard"
         Grid.Column="1"
         Grid.Row="0"
         Style="{StaticResource MenuButtonTheme}" 
         Tag="/Images/image2.png">
        </RadioButton>
```

Comment: I already did this. Please see my updated post :D

Comment: I could not change the background image according to IsChecked true and false on the xaml side. It can be solved by taking a little time. That's all I can do :)

Comment: well, this solved the "default" image display (when the button is not clicked). I still need to figure out about changing the image depending on the button state.

Comment: You can change it by giving the RadioButton a name, using `RadioBt.Tag = "/Images/image.png";`  in the background code.

Comment: how do I do that in code behind? this is my first time creating ui in wpf.

Comment: In a single design, it may not be possible without writing code to the background. In this case you will need to write a new style file for each radioButton.

If it is possible I do not know.